# Term to say "how much space a specific market has for new sellers"

Tags: terminology

For example, let's say there is a lot of people demanding furniture but very few sellers, how is the term to say "there's space" / good oportunities due to high demand + little demand satisfaction.

Comment: Isn't this "demand capacity" for the market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would say that it's a "seller's market", meaning that the most of the advantage is with the seller, who would be more free to set a higher price.

The opposite is, logically, a "buyer's market", when there are lots of sellers and few buyers.

Answer (score 5):

As Chad rightly points out, "seller's market" is often used to describe the general context of demand exceeding supply for an established "commodity" (i.e. - anything we're used to thinking of in terms of it being bought and sold, such as houses, second-hand cars, etc.).

But when talking about something that *isn't* commonly thought of as a "tradeable commodity" (such as a [left-handed sewing machine](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130405010412AAUtsL5)), you might say there's a [***gap in the market***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gap%20in%20the%20market%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (to be exploited/served).

Comment: Good point! Hadn't thought of that angle.

Answer (score 4):

You could describe this scenario as *low market saturation*. Market saturation describes the ratio of supply (especially number of supply sources) to demand: in highly saturated markets, most or all demand is met, leaving little room for growth. In an unsaturated market, there's a surplus of demand and relatively few competing supply sources.